# Correct dependency management with Spring Zuul and Spring Initializer

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix

I want to implement some hello world Spring Zuul project based on [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/zuul-load-balancing) and [this pt-br blog](https://emmanuelneri.com.br/2018/05/02/criando-proxy-de-apis-com-spring-cloud-zuul-e-eureka/).

As the first uses this non-Spring artifact

```
<groupId>com.baeldung.spring.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud</artifactId>
```

as parent and the second uses [this deprecated artifact](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-netflix-core/2.1.0.RELEASE) at `dependencyManagement`, I decided to use [spring initalizr](https://start.spring.io/) only adding Zuul to my dependencies. But when I run it, I get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.netflix.zuul.monitoring.CounterFactory
```

I'm using this annotations at my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableZuulProxy
@EnableDiscoveryClient
```

Comment: please paste you pom.xml completely

Comment: @clevertension my pom is exactly the one generated by spring initalizer with only `Zuul` added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had already tried to delete `.m2` folder and this didn't work, I assume my download didn't complete successfully again. But my error changed to

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter
```

followed by

```
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid block type
```

That turned this error is commonly caused by invalid `.m2` jars.

After deleting [everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) at `.m2` with 'zuul' on it, including `com/netflix/zuul`(outside spring directory), and using `mvn clean package -U` with maven 3.5.4 I finally successfully initiated my application.